# How to put space between variables in counting C++?

Tags: c++, printing, integer, cout

I am programming in C++.
I have `A = 1`  and `B = 2`
I want to have `1 2` in my output my code is this:

```
cout<<a<<b;
```

What should I write instead of this?

Thanks for your helping

Comment: Output a space character as well: `std::cout << a << ' ' << b;`

Answer (score 0):

> use " "

cout << a << " " << b;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a space between, just use `<<" "<<`.

But if you want to start from a new space just put `<<endl;`

If you are talking about concatenation, using " " and inputting something inside could be a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your great comment 